For $R=\mathbb{k}[x,y]$, $\operatorname{Hom}_R(M,R)$ is always free.
Let $R=\mathbb{k}[x,y]$ be the polynomial ring with two variables over a field $\mathbb{k}$.
I claim that $\operatorname{Hom}_R(M,R)$ is always free
for any finitely generated $R$-module $M$.
I believe it is true but I couldn't find a way to prove it nor a counterexample.
I would appreciate any help with it.

For one variable case, $R=\mathbb{k}[x]$, the claim holds true:
Choose a presentation $R^n\rightarrow M \rightarrow 0$
and taking $\operatorname{Hom}_R(-,R)$ gives $0\rightarrow \operatorname{Hom}_R(M,R)\rightarrow R^n$.
But $R=\mathbb{k}[x]$ is PID and so any submodule of a free $R$-module is again a free module.

Why do you believe this to be true? What inspired the conjecture?

@Aaron It holds true for the polynomial ring with one variable because it is a PID. But for two variable case, it is not a PID any more so I cannot repeat the proof. But still I don't have a counterexample. I added it in the main post. Thanks!

What examples have you tried to construct a counterexample?  You would need $M$ not to be free itself, did you try taking, say, $M=(x,y)\subset R$, the ideal generated by $x$ and $y$? (I haven't worked out that example, but it's the first one I would try).

@Aaron Indeed, if $M$ is a submodule of $R$, it seems to be true that $\operatorname{Hom}_R(M,R) \cong R$. Because $R$ is still UFD, the image of any element of $M$ determines the image of others; there are choices as many as $R$.

Dual of any finitely generated module is reflexive and so in your case has depth at least two. Then use Auslamder - Buchsbaum theorem to show that the module is projective and use Seshadri's theorem to show freeness.

@Mohan Can we use Auslander-Buchsbaum theorem also for a non-local ring?

You can localize to check projectivity. Of course to apply Seshadri's theorem you cannot.

@Ramanasa In this case our ring is graded so it works out
